# how Ajax request is sent by browser

Tags: ajax, http, networking

I want to ask you how the browser sends ajax request i mean what is the format of ajax request. So what is actual format of AJAX request sent by browser.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you install Firefox and Firebug you can see for yourself:

http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/08/01/How-to-debug-XmlHttpRequest-with-Firebug.aspx

Comment: Or install Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) and use any browser you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's a standard HTTP request - just like any other request the browser makes.

You can read more about the [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) call and indeed the structure of a [HTTP request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) on WikiPedia.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is shorthand for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML and does not define a standard on how the data is transferred.
Because the browsers are designed primarily as HTTP clients you should study GET and POST and maybe PUT and DELETE for RESTful web services.

Comment: i precisely want to know the things behind so for that will you please elaborate a bit more